# Creating new column in the model instead of the migration

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to learn laravel and its going well. But there is something about Eloquent that seems really weird to me.

Apparently you should make a model for every table and then make a migration and add new columns to the migration.

But if I can't add new columns in the model class and have to edit the migration file, then what's the point of having the model class in the first place?

Comment: Model will link database table and migration is for schema

Comment: The migration is purely for editing the table schema (structure). The model is used to query and manipulate the data in that table. You can use migrations without models and vice versa. If you do add a column with a migration then it is more than likely that you will need to update the model anyway e.g. updating the `$fillable` or `$casts` properties, but depending on how you've set your model up and what the column is you might not need to do that.

Answer (score 2):

## Migrations

Migrations are like version control for your database, allowing your team to easily modify and share the application's database schema. Migrations are typically paired with Laravel's schema builder to easily build your application's database schema. If you have ever had to tell a teammate to manually add a column to their local database schema, you've faced the problem that database migrations solve.

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#introduction)

## Models

The Eloquent ORM included with Laravel provides a beautiful, simple ActiveRecord implementation for working with your database. Each database table has a corresponding "Model" which is used to interact with that table. Models allow you to query for data in your tables, as well as insert new records into the table.

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#introduction)

### Conclusion

A summary would be that migrations allow you to structure your database and make sure the database stays the same, even when you're using a version control system or multiple environments. Models are your the way you communicate with the contents of said database.

Structure -> migration

Data -> model

Answer (score 0):

Your migration files contain the database schema and they are used to create the database tables. And the models are used to interact with those tables. Your models extend `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class that's responsible for querying the database for CRUD operations.

Your migrations extend `Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration` class and the `Migration` class is responsible for creating or dropping the tables and columns based on your defined schema.

So getting back to your main question, keeping these two logics in different classes is a better way to separate the stuff. If you would dump all the logic (both tables creation and CRUD operations) in a single class, that'd not be as clean as how it is done in Laravel.

References:

1. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent
2. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations